# matlab simulink waveform draw

Tags: matlab, plot, scope, simulink, waveform

I want to plot gmsk modulator "signal wave form" in simulink. but because gmsk modulator output is complex array, scope can't show it directly, and when I use complex to real / image converter, it's wave form is clearly just flat lines "fig1" rather than "fig2".so i should convert them to sin and cos with their respectively phase and amplitude but don't know how to do it yet. i want to plot something like this "fig2"
thank you.[simulink project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toOG1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

When using blocks from the `DSP Blockset` or the `Communications Blockset` you'd usually also use the specialized viewers available with those blocksets to view signals.  In this case you most likely want the [Spectrum Analyzer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/spectrumanalyzer.html).

To get familiar with various ways of viewing this type of signal have a look at some of the examples.  For instance,

```
>> commadjcochanint
```